# codeigniter controller input Hebrew letters

Tags: php, codeigniter, hebrew

I have a function in the controller that gets a string and then queries the database (via the model) for records that have this string as their name. This works fine with English but I have a problem when the input is in Hebrew. When I echo the string I see something like %D7%91 and the query fails.
All database tables entries are defined as utf8_general_ci.

My controller code:

```
function get_records_by_name($name)
{
            echo 'searching for: '.$name.'</br>';
    $keys = new DMkeys() ; 

    $query = $keys->get_keys();

    $arr = array();

    $count = 0;

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
    {
        if(stristr($row->name, $name) != FALSE)
        {
            $arr[] = $row->name;
            $count++;
            echo $row->name.'</br>';
        }
    }

    $result = array('count' => $count, 'list' => $arr);

    echo json_encode($result) ;  
}
```

My model code:

```
function get_keys()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('keys');
    return $query;
}
```

Thanks,
  Simon

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: code added to the question

Comment: can you try to change your encoding in CI/config.php to UTF-16 instead of UTF-8 it fixed the issue for me before.

Comment: I have changed to: $config['charset'] = 'UTF-16'; but it did not solve the problem for me

Comment: probably you need to decode the variable first try `$name = urldecode($name);`

Comment: great it solved that problem. 
Now I see that the text in the JSON array is not Hebrew. Should I do something before adding to the array?

Comment: i'm not sure what is your `DMKeys` but probably you need to decode them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the variable before using it, try:

```
$name = urldecode($name);
```